# Cassandra version 2.1.3 java.lang.AssertionError: attempted to delete non-existing file system-compaction_history

Tags: cassandra

I upgraded from Cassandra 2.1.2 to 2.1.3 following the upgrade instructions. However, I started to see this new `java.lang.AssertionError`. See log below.

Environment: Windows 7 (yes I konw...), Java 1.8.0_11

```
ERROR [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2015-04-05 20:34:39,638 CassandraDaemon.java:167 - Exception in thread Thread[NonPeriodicTasks:1,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: attempted to delete non-existing file system-compaction_history-tmplink-ka-548-Data.db
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.deleteWithConfirm(FileUtils.java:126) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader$Tidier$1.run(SSTableReader.java:2072) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_11]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_11]
```

Does anyone know what this error is about and how I can correct this? Or if there is already an open JIRA at Apache?

Answer (score 1):

See open JIRA ticket at the link below on this issue. Basically this is potentially a known issue. bug has been filed.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9121